# Laravel get relationship model within object after save()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using **laravel 4.2**.

I have two models as below :

```
class User extends Eloquent{
   protected $table = 'users';

   public function user_card_details(){
        return $this->hasMany('User_card_details');
   }
}
```

And

```
class User_card_details extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'user_card_details';

    public $timestamps = true;

    public $softdeletes = true;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User')->first();
    }
}
```

And I can save the relationship record using :

```
$user_card_details = new User_card_details();
$user_card_details->card_number = Input::get('card_number');
$user_card_details->card_exp_month = Input::get('card_expires_m');
$user_card_details->card_exp_year = Input::get('card_expires_y');
$user_card_details->card_cvv = Input::get('card_cvv');
$user->user_card_details()->save($user_card_details);
```

Up to this it works fine for me.

After `save()` , I want the user object should be populated with `user_details`.

So if I want to use the properties, I can use it like :

`echo $user->user_card_details->card_number`;

But it is not working now.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `()` to get the actual model or collection:

```
echo $user->user_card_details->card_number;
```

When you're calling the actual function, you'll receive an instance of the Query builder.

Also, it seems that you're not persisting your `$user_card_details`-object before you try to bind it to your user:

```
$user_card_details = new User_card_details();
$user_card_details->card_number = Input::get('card_number');
$user_card_details->card_exp_month = Input::get('card_expires_m');
$user_card_details->card_exp_year = Input::get('card_expires_y');
$user_card_details->card_cvv = Input::get('card_cvv');
$user_card_details->save(); //Added this line.

$user->user_card_details()->save($user_card_details);
```

The more correct way would be:

```
$user_card_details = [
        'card_number'    => Input::get( 'card_number' ),
        'card_exp_month' => Input::get( 'card_expires_m' ),
        'card_exp_year'  => Input::get( 'card_expires_y' ),
        'card_cvv'       => Input::get( 'card_cvv' ),
    ];

$userCardDetailObj = $user->user_card_details()->create( $user_card_details );
```

Now, your `User_card_detail`-instance will be available as the returned object.

Comment: If I user print_r($user->toArray()) then it is not showing the user_details. Let me check again.

Comment: `$user->user_card_details->first()` or `$user->user_card_details()->first()` as the relationship is a `hasMany` and will return a `Collection` of models not a single model.

Comment: In that case, I think it will make another database call. It will not be an efficient way to get the records that I have already.

Comment: In this case also it returns error : Call to a member function first() on a non-object

Comment: You're saving `user_card_details()` and trying to get `user_details`. Which one is right?

Comment: @Dencker That was typo, I have updated it in the question. I want the user_card_details from $user.

Comment: @Dencker I am doing the same, look at my code in question. The thing is after saving the relationship record, I want to get the relational object without any other query. And that is not working. echo $user->user_card_details->card_number;

Comment: Oops.. Then it will make two database transections